# how to use extern variable string in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to access string from one class to other class in iphone application

or how to use extern variable in iphone.

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have asked plenty of questions but never accepted any answer - read the StackOverflow FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

use NSUserDefault or use extern varible...create .h file first clear all syntex in .h file then write extern NSString *name declaration, then inialise into appdelegate initialization file as above the implementation section just like NSString *name; now whenever you want to use name string in any file you just want declare your .h file and you can use your name variable..
example

```
extern NSString *userBlnc;  
extern NSString *canReq;   
extern NSString *userName;
```

declaration in appdelegate.m

```
#import "Config.h"

NSString *userBlnc;  
NSString *canReq;  
NSString *userName; 

@implementation ***************
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a look at Setter and Getter theory.

Answer (score 0):

Declare them in your header as follows:

```
extern NSString *const kExternForExample;
```

Comment: thanks , but   i have declare    extern NSString *const kExternForExample;
in header of the class , now i want to access this variable in other class  , so what we do in other class with this variable

Comment: Import the header file in the other class implementation file.